# Como Release App

Tags: android, android-studio

Terminei meu aplicativo agora deixar pronto para Play Store
Vi no site que tenho que configurar o Gradle, adicionar o código release.

Peguei esse código e ainda não entendi como usar.

```
release {
      storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
      storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
      keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
      keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa gerar o release.store.
Apos regar, você vai configurar no Generate Signer APK.

E coloque os dados que usar no Generate Signer APK, no seu gradle.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: é verdade! Depois de feito apareceu o código no gradle. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo `build.gradle (Module:app)` adicione o seguinte código:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
            storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
            storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
        }
    }
....
}
```

Este contém as informações para realizar a assinatura da apk. Estas informações ficam no arquivo `grade.properties`:

```
STORE_FILE=../SEU_AQUIVO_DE_ASSINATURA.keystore
STORE_PASSWORD=SUA SENHA 
KEY_ALIAS=SEU ALIAS
KEY_PASSWORD=SUA SENHA DO ALIAS
```

Neste caso, deixamos o `SEU_AQUIVO_DE_ASSINATURA` na raiz do projeto (ao lado da pasta app).

Agora vamos informar que iremos utilizar esta assinatura no build ( `signingConfig signingConfigs.config`):

```
buildTypes {
// Release
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
//Debug
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```